# how to send value to servlet from javascript (Dynamically creates text box)

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

I am developing a project in java web application using jsp/servlet.

Here in this page I am creating a text box with the help of java script.

```
 <script>
 var newInput4=document.createElement("input");
newInput4.className="form-control ";
newInput4.name="totalunit"+instance;
newInput4.placeholder="Unit";   
newInput4.type="text";
</script>
```

Problem is that how could I entry in database from servlet Because this input dynamically created.

```
newInput4.name="totalunit"+instance;
```

this line dynamically name update .

how to send "name" to servlet?

Comment: By sticking it in a html form and submitting the form like usual? I'd think your problem would be more on the server side - you get a request and then how do you know which name to use to fetch the submitted data. You'd have to explain more where this 'instance' variable is coming from.

Comment: can you please tell me how to send javascript name to servlet page

newInput4.name="totalunit"+instance;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like following way..

```
<script>
  var newInput4=document.createElement("input");
  newInput4.className="form-control ";
  newInput4.name="totalunit1";
  newInput4.placeholder="Unit";   
  newInput4.type="text";
  var formId = document.getElementById('formInput');
  newInput4.appendChild(formId);

</script>

<form method="GET" id="formInput" action="application/servletname"> //
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

//Serveletname.Java
String id = request.getParameter("totalunit1");
```

Comment: what is formInput ?
    var formId = document.getElementById('formInput');
newInput 4.name is static totalunit1;
how it works

Comment: formInput is id of the form. When user click on submit, we are appending the input field dynamically into form using form Id(i.e., formInput)

Comment: bro if you have an example please mail me. mehandih@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Okay !!

If that is dynamically generated value then dynamically set the value to `Hidden` variable

```
 <script>
  var newInput4=document.createElement("input");
  newInput4.className="form-control ";
  newInput4.name="totalunit"+instance;
  newInput4.placeholder="Unit";   
  newInput4.type="text";

   document.getElementById("YourHiddenID").value = document.getElementByName("totalunit"+instance).value;

</script>



      <html>
        <input type="hidden" id = "YourHiddenID" >
       </html>
```

In your Servlet class

```
      Srtring yourDesiredValue = request.getParameter("YourHiddenID");
```

Comment: Srtring yourDesiredValue;

Comment: What do you mean not working ? any error or exception where you stuck please explain

Comment: bro how you enter your value into db without textbox name ?