# How to fetch the name from JavaScript? JavaScript creates new input on every click

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

I am creating a new input-box by clicking on a link with the help of Javascript.

Here's the Javascript code:

```
<script>
var instance = 1;
function myFunction(event) {
    instance++;
    var DivAllPrime=document.getElementById("divPrime");

    var newLabel1 = document.createElement("label");
    newLabel1.id = "label" + instance;
    newLabel1.innerHTML = 'label '+instance;
    newLabel1.className="col-md-4 formLineHeight";

    var newInput2=document.createElement("input");
    newInput2.id="ingredient"+instance;
    newInput2.name="ingredient"+instance;
    newInput2.className="form-control ";
    newInput2.placeholder="Ingredient";
    newInput2.name="ingredient"+instance;

    var newDiv2=document.createElement("div");
    newDiv2.className="col-md-3  marginBottom10";
    newDiv2.appendChild(newInput2);

    DivAllPrime.appendChild(newLabel1);
    DivAllPrime.appendChild(newDiv2);

    var newInput4=document.createElement("input");
    newInput4.className="form-control ";
    newInput4.name="totalunit"+instance;
    newInput4.placeholder="Unit";   
    newInput4.type="text";

    var newDiv3=document.createElement("div");
    newDiv3.className="col-md-2  marginBottom10";
    newDiv3.appendChild(newInput4);
    DivAllPrime.appendChild(newDiv3);

    var newInput5=document.createElement("select");
    newInput5.id="unit"+instance;
    newInput5.name="unit"+instance;
    newInput5.className="form-control ";

    var newDiv4=document.createElement("div");
    newDiv4.className="col-md-2  marginBottom10";

    var newInput6=document.createElement("option");
    newInput6.value="gram";
    newInput6.innerHTML="Gram"; 
    newInput6.selected=true;
    newInput5.appendChild(newInput6);

    var newInput7=document.createElement("option");
    newInput7.value="ml";
    newInput7.innerHTML="ML";
    newInput5.appendChild(newInput7);
    newDiv4.appendChild(newInput5);
    DivAllPrime.appendChild(newDiv4);
    return false;
}
</script>
```

This line sets the name of the new input dynamically:

```
newInput4.name="totalunit"+instance;
```

How can I get the name and send it to the servlet?

Comment: What happened with your indentation..?

Comment: I am not able to send variable name to servlet.

Comment: Instead of asking same question, update code in your previous question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31019248/how-to-send-value-to-servlet-from-javascript-dynamically-creates-text-box